# Create a new matrix based on a previous one in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix as follows:

```
         >  Mat=matrix(c(1,1,0,1,1,2,1,Inf), nrow=4, ncol=2)
         > Mat
             [,1] [,2]
       [1,]    1    1
       [2,]    1    2
       [3,]    0    1
       [4,]    1  Inf
```

I want to create a new matrix based on the above matrix as follows: when the value of first column equals to the second column, put the same value in the first column of the new matrix, when we have two different values in both columns, put the mean of two values for the first column of the new matrix, and when the value of second column is Inf, put the value of first column in the first column of the new matrix. For the second column values of the new matrix, only when the value of the second column in the first matrix is Inf, put the value equals to 0, otherwise equals to 1. The final new matrix is as follows:

```
      > newMat=matrix(c(1,1.5,0.5,1, 1,1,1,0), nrow=4,ncol=2)
      > newMat
           [,1] [,2]
      [1,]  1.0    1
      [2,]  1.5    1
      [3,]  0.5    1
      [4,]  1.0    0
```

How can I create the new matrix in R?

Answer (score 2):

We  can use

```
Mat[,1]  <-  rowMeans(Mat)
i1 <- is.infinite(Mat[,2])
Mat[,2] <- +(!i1)
Mat[i1,1] <- 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the second column of the new matrix is not right.

Comment: @shany sorry, it needs negation.  Updated

Comment: If instead on one for the last row and first column of the new matrix, I want to put the value in the last row and first column of previous matrix in R, what should I do?

Comment: Any value which is in the last row and first column.

Answer (score 1):

Extended example data to illustrate case where inf is in first column;

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, Inf, 1, 2, 1, Inf, 1), ncol=2)
m

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1  Inf
[5,]  Inf    1
```

Solution using base `R`:

1.Copy `m` to `new_m`

```
m_new <- m
```

2.Identify rows where we need to change the values:

```
different_values <- m[, 1] != m[, 2]
second_is_inf <- is.infinite(abs(m[, 2]))
```

3.Apply changes:

```
m_new[different_values & !second_is_inf, 1] <- rowSums(m[different_values & !second_is_inf, 1:2])/2

m_new[second_is_inf, 2] <- 0


m_new
```

Returns:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.0    1
[2,]  1.5    2
[3,]  0.5    1
[4,]  1.0    0
[5,]  Inf    1
```